# Proof check: Isoperimetric inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

**My Proof:**

Let the arc-length parametrization of the curve be $\gamma(s) = \langle x(s),y(s)\rangle$. By Green's Theorem, the area $\mathcal{A}$ is

$$ \mathcal{A} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} -y(s)x'(s) dx$$

Then, consider the following:

$$\pi-\mathcal{A}=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}ds - \int_{0}^{2\pi} -y(x) x'(s) ds $$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} 1+2y(x)x'(s) ds$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (x' + y)^2 ds + \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} -y^2 + (y'(s))^2 ds$$

The first integral is obviously greater than zero. The second integral is not so obvious, but since we have, by Parsevel's identity,

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (y'(s))^2 ds - \int_0^{2\pi} y^2 ds=\sum|na_n|^2 - \sum|a_n|^2 = \sum|a_n|^2(n^2-1)$$

Since, by assumption, $\int_{0}^{2\pi} y(s) ds = 0$, as a result, $a_0 = 0$. So the above sum is always greater than $0$ since $|n|\ge 1$.
So we have showed that $\pi \ge \mathcal{A}$.

Then we study when we have equality. **(I am not very confident about the following part).** Suppose we do have the equality, then we must have both integrals equal to zero. That is, we must have

$$x'(s) = -y(s)$$ and the only values $n$ would take are $1$ and $-1$. That implies that

$$y(s) = a_1 e^{is} + a_{-1}e^{-is} = a_1\cos(s) + a_1\sin(s)i + a_{-1}\cos(s) - a_{-1}\sin(s)i$$

Since we know that $y(s)$ is actually real, we must have $a_1 = a_{-1}$ and thus

$$y(s) = 2a_1\cos(x)$$

This would imply that

$$x(t) = 2a_1\sin(t)$$

This finishes the proof.

Comment: $n$ might be zero too, so saying that $(n^2-1)\ge 0$ after using Parseval (on the fifth line) is not valid.

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could justify why the only values for $n$ are $\pm 1$ when you are considering the equality part.