# Show that the isoperimetric inequality is equivalent to Wirtinger's inequality...

Tags: fourier-analysis

> Show that the isoperimetric inequality is equivalent to
>   Wirtinger's inequality, which says that if $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, of class $C^1$, and satisfies $\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)dt=0$, then $$\int_0^{2\pi}|f(t)|^2dt\leq \int_0^{2\pi}|f'(t)|^2dt$$
>   with equality if and only if $f(t) = A\sin t + B \cos t$

Part of the proof:
(Isoperimetric $\implies$ Wirtinger)
If we re-parametrize $t = ks$ with $k = T/(2\pi)$, then the change of variable shows that it is sufficient to prove the claim for the period being $2\pi$.
Given f with mean 0. we found $F(t) :=\int_0^t f(s) ds$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function. So the isoperimetric and Hölder inequalities imply
$$\int_0^{2\pi}f^2(t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)F'(t)dt$$ $$ \leq \frac 1 {4\pi}\left (\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt {(f'(t))^2 + (F'(t))^2}dt\right )^2 \tag{1}$$  $$ \leq \frac 1 2 \int_0^{2\pi}(f'(t))^2 +f(t)^2 dt \tag{2}$$
which is equivalent to the Wirtinger's inequality (*How?*).
(Is $\frac 1 2 \int_0^{2\pi}(f'(t))^2 +f(t)^2 dt$ equivalent to $\int_0^{2\pi}|f'(t)|^2dt$? )

Could you also show how to arrive $(1)$ and $(2)$ ?

**Some defs and thms**:

- If $\Gamma$ is parametrized by $\gamma (s) = (x(s), y(s))$, then the length of the curve $\Gamma$ is defined by $l=\int_a^b |\gamma '(s)|ds=\int_a^b{x'(s)^2+ y'(s)^2}ds$
- (the isoperimetric inequality): 
  Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a simple closed curve in $\mathbb R^2$ of length
  $l$, and let $\mathcal A$ denote the area of the region enclosed by this curve. Then
  $$\mathcal A\leq \frac {l^2}{4\pi}$$
  with equality if and only if $\Gamma$ is a circle.
- the area $\mathcal A $ of the region enclosed by a simple closed curve $\Gamma$ is given by $\frac12 \left |\int_a^b (x(s)y'(s)-y(s)x'(s))\,ds\right |$

Comment: [Isoperimetric inequality implies Wirtinger's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14996) has one direction, [Proof check: Isoperimetric inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1814198) has the other.

Answer (score 2):

For step 1, use isoperimetric inequality:
$$\mathcal A \le \frac{l^{2}}{4\pi}$$
Which can also be written as 
$$\int _{a}^{b}x(s)y^{'}(s)ds \le \int _{a}^{b}(x^{'}(s)^{2}+y^{'}(s)^{2})^{1/2}ds.$$
if $\Gamma$ is parametrized by $\gamma=(x(s),y(s))$
Then substitute $f(t)=x(t)$ and $F^{'}(t)=y^{'}(t)$.
For step 2, use Holder inequality:
$$\int_{a}^{b}| f(x)g(x) |dx \le (\int_{a}^{b} | f(x)|^{p}dx)^{1/p}(\int_{a}^{b}| g(x)| ^{q}dx)^{1/q}$$
For $(q, p) \in (1,\infty), \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

Substitute $g(t)=1$, $f(t)=\sqrt{f^{'}(t)^{2}+F^{'}(t)^{2}}dt$ and $p=q=2$ to get

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{f^{'}(t)^{2}+F^{'}(t)^{2}} \le \sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{2\pi}(f^{'}(t))^{2}+(f(t))^{2}dt.} $$

Then

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f^{2}(x)dt\le \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (f^{'}(t))^{2}+(f(t))^{2}dt \to \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f^{2}(t)dt\le \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (f^{'}(t))^{2}dt.$$
Which is just Wirtinger's inequality.